# How to print a Pdf file in zebra GK420t without using any middleware software for converting pdf to ZPL on linux?

Tags: printing, ubuntu-14.04, zebra-printers

I want to print a pdf file on Zebra GK420t . But I'm unable to do so (printer doesn't prints anything,doesn't even shows any job in the queue).Is there any way to convert that pdf ? I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and was trying to print the file using CUP ,i used the command
 `lp -d <Printer_name> *.pdf` .

I searched google for this query too and found a link [Link-Os virtual device](https://km.zebra.com/resources/sites/ZEBRA/content/live/WHITE_PAPERS/0/WH127/en_US/Link-OS%20PDF%20Virtual%20Device.pdf)

But I'm unable to understand this. Please help as I'm a newbie.

Comment: And just installing one of the Zebra drivers won't work? They tend to do so on Windows where they take the PDF and convert it down to an image which it prints, even though the preferred way is to write the label using ZPLII

Comment: "Zebra does not provide a driver for use on Linux/Unix or Mac OS X operating systems but instead suggests the use of the Common Unix Printing System (CUPS) driver."      source :https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7680

Comment: Right on. Not used to use any drivers with thermal printers. I'll ask one of my colleagues and get back to you. I'm mainly into developing applications that use raw ZPLII and push it directly to the printer.

Comment: @JaggenSWE :Thanks !

Comment: What you need to do to achieve this is, unfortunately, to convert the PDF down to an image and then run it through the Zebra SDK, which has Components for preparing the image for use with the Zebra printer, and then push it to the printer as part of a ZPL/EPL print job.

Comment: For single jobs this sounds fine but for multiple jobs it could be a little cumbersome. Btw thanks for the help !

Comment: Ah, well, this entails that you do some kind of program that will take care of things for you of course. Doing it manually would be a real hassle.